# Select a few coordinates from a large set that look evenly distributed in the area

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm, coordinates

I have a MySQL table with area and lat/lon location columns. Every area has many locations, say `20.000`. Is there a way to pick just a few, say `100`, that look somewhat evenly distributed on the map?

The distribution doesn't have to be perfect, query speed is more important. If that is not possible directly with MySQL a very fast algorithm that somehow picks evenly distributed locations might also work.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: answering some requests in comments. The data doesn't have something that can be used, it's just area and coordinates of locations, example:

```
+-------+--------------+----------+-----------+------------+--------+--------+
| id    | area         | postcode | lat       | lon        | colour | size   |
+-------+--------------+----------+-----------+------------+--------+--------+
| 16895 | Athens       |    10431 | 37.983917 | 23.7293599 | red    | big    |
| 16995 | Athens       |    11523 | 37.883917 | 23.8293599 | green  | medium |
| 16996 | Athens       |    10432 | 37.783917 | 23.7293599 | yellow | small  |
| 17000 | Thessaloniki |    54453 | 40.783917 | 22.7293599 | green  | small  |
+-------+--------------+----------+-----------+------------+--------+--------+
```

There are some more columns with characteristics but those are just used for filtering.

I did try getting the `nth` row in the meantime, it seems to work although a bit slow

```
SET @a = 0;
select * from `locations` where (@a := @a + 1) % 200 = 0
```

using `random()` also works but a bit slow too.

Edit2: Turns out it was easy to add postal codes on the table. Having that, getting grouped by postal code seems to give a nice to the eye result. Only issue is that there are very large areas with around 3000 distinct postcodes and getting just 100 may end up many of them show in one place, so will probably need to further process in PHP.

Edit3, answering @RickJames questions in comments so they are in one place:

1. Please define "evenly distributed" -- evenly spaced in latitude? no two are "close" to each other? etc.

   - "Evenly distributed" was a bad choice of words. We just want to show some locations on the area that are not all in one place
2. Are the "areas" rectangles? Hexagons? Or gerrymandered congressional districts?

   - They can be thought roughly as rectangles but it shouldn't matter. Important thing I missed, we also need to show locations from multiple areas. Areas may be far apart from each other or neighboring (but not overlap). In that case we'd want the sample of 100 to be split between the areas.
3. Is the "100 per area" fixed? Or can it be "about 100"

   - It's not fixed, it's around 100 but we can change this if it doesn't look nice
4. Is there an AUTO_INCREMENT id on the table? Are there gaps in the numbers?

   - Yes there is an `AUTO_INCREMENT` id and can have gaps
5. Has the problem changed from "100 per area" to "1 per postal code"?

   - Nope the problem is still the same, "show 100 per area in a way that not all of them are in the same place", how this is done it doesn't matter
6. What are the total row count and desired number of rows in output?

   - Total row count depends on area and criteria, it can be up to 40k in an area. If total is more than `1000` we want to fall back showing just a random of `100`. If `1000` or less we can just show all of them
7. Do you need a different sample each time you run the query?

   - Same sample or different sample even with the same criteria is fine
8. Are you willing to add a column to the table?

   - It's not up to me but if I have good argument then most probably we can add a new column

Comment: This algorithm is well-known. It is pre-calculation. Create such groups when you have a time for this. Then, when needed, simply retrieve previously created group(s).

Comment: You could subdivide each area into 100 evenly distributed subareas, and save this in every row. When you run the query you simply select one row from each subarea.

Comment: This is not necessary a good solution, but just check for speed. `SELECT distinct * FROM locations order by rand() Limit 200`. The idea is when no proper criteria, even some random points can somehow fit.(order is irrelevant if there will be no arrows to point directions). If use mysql ver >= 8, them maybe check `rank()`

Comment: Please define "evenly distributed" -- evenly spaced in latitude?  no two are "close" to each other?  etc.  I can help with "[_Random rows_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/random) , but they may not be "evenly distributed" by any metric.

Comment: @TraianGEICU - That query and the OP's (and lots of other obvious queries) require a full table scan.  See my link (above) for kludges that avoid a full scan.

Comment: Are the "areas" rectangles?  Hexagons?  Or gerrymandered congressional districts?

Comment: Is the "100 per area" fixed?  Or can it be "about 100".  I ask because there are 'random' techniques that will give only "about 100".  (I'm not concerned about the "20K".)  How many "areas" are there?  Do you want to find 100 for each area in a single query?  Or are you just asking for 100 in a particular area?

Comment: Is there an `AUTO_INCREMENT` id on the table?  Are there gaps in the numbers?  I have lots of ideas, but I need the Question to be tightened up before I present them.

Comment: @RickJames Yes there is an autoincrement `id` but may have gaps, also `id` is not sorted by `area`. About "evenly distributed" it's much simpler, it simply means not all locations will show in the lower left of an area for example. Areas can be thought roughly as rectangles, so partitioning the area in 4 boxes and showing random 25 in each should be enough.

Comment: @RickJames had a quick look in the link you posted, it looks very interesting and promising, will try that. "100 per area" is not fixed can show more or a few less, it's not important. 
General question: Any idea if that will scope well when dealing with a few million results?

Comment: I see that a bunch of comments are now hidden because of deleting an Answer.  With more specifics in your Question, I may attempt an Answer.  I'm still leaning toward my "random rows" link as the core of the solution.  It may have to use [_Groupwise-Max_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max), too.

Comment: @RickJames I've added some updates to the answer, not sure what more is needed. We may have a good solution (fast) after adding postal codes on the table but still welcome anything you can propose.

Comment: @realife - Sorry, more questions:  Has the problem changed from "100 per area" to "1 per postal code"?  What are the total row count and desired number of rows in output?  Do you need a different sample each time you run the query?

Comment: @RickJames I believe the problem is the same, will still show "100 per area". Just getting those  100 from 100 distinct postal codes seem to distribute well over the area. Yeah, sample should differ according to criteria (example `colour`). Ideally I would get the same sample for same criteria but not required, so random is definitely a good choice if can be made faster, especially if there is no need for fetching thousands of records and PHP processing to get 100 out of them.

Comment: @realife - Any use of `ORDER BY RAND()` will fetch all the rows, sort the entire set, then deliver the subset.  I'm trying to help you find a way to avoid that.

Comment: @RickJames yes. If you have a solution where using random is fast I will accept it, even if it doesn't look too good visually I will use the base query to get more than 100 records, get extreme bounds to separate the area in four squares and get 25 locations from each square. I understand that doing that directly in MySQL may not be possible.

Comment: @realife - Are you willing to add a column to the table?  We can discuss how it can help with randomness without leading to a full table scan.  Before I attempt to spell out the details, please answer the other little questions I have asked.

Comment: @RickJames I've added another edit so we have all questions and answers in one place. Let me know if I missed something. I think the problem is well defined now. But if you need more specifics let me know. I've also seem a chat functionality at some point maybe more appropriate to continue there

Comment: @realife -  Thanks for the added info.  One algorithm has the potential flaw(?) that it may find only 5 items in one 'area', while finding 2000 in another area.  Are the areas that inconsistent?  Is the problem akin to cities in the world (area=country) and/or houses in Greece (area = Region)?  Would it be OK to run a slow process to put some items in another [smaller] table, then work from that?

Comment: @RickJames searching can be done among areas of same type, example among region types or only among city types etc. so we can safely say they will have about the same number of items, there wont be a case where one area can have 400 times more items that another area of the same type.

Comment: @realife - "type" is a new thingie.  My Answer may need tweaking to allow for "type"?

Comment: @RickJames as far as I can tell it shouldn't matter, it just means when you want multiple areas, you can only search by same area type. Your idea is a good base, done properly it will create a smaller table with locations distributed in all country. Choosing area (of any type) will just restrict locations in that area but will still look distributed.

Comment: @realife - I may have been thinking 100 per area; did you want 100 total, instead?

Comment: @realife - Perhaps this is a good example:  "Areas" are Postal codes in Greece (which has a scattering of islands).  And "locations" are seafood restaurants?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach that *may* satisfy the goals.

1. Preprocess the table, making a new table, to get rid of "duplicate" items.
2. If the new table is small enough, a full scan of it may be fast enough.

As for "duplicates", consider this as a crude way to discover that two items land in the same spot:

```
 SELECT  ROUND(latitude * 5),
         ROUND(longitude * 3),
         MIN(id) AS id_to_keep
     FROM tbl
     GROUP BY 1,2
```

The "5" and "3" can be tweaked upward (or downard) to cause more (or fewer) ids to be kept.  "5" and "3" are different because of the way the lat/lng are laid out; that ratio might work most temperate latitudes.  (Use equal numbers near the equator, use a bigger ration for higher latitudes.)

There is a minor flaw...  Two items very close to each other might be across the boundaries created by those `ROUNDs`.

How many rows are in the original table?  How many rows does the above query generate?  ( `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ( ... ) x;` )

Comment: thanks, your idea looks like a good solution. Will create the table you describe and come back for any feedback. If I see it takes much time I will accept the answer anyway because it really seems like something that could work, just depends on creating the correct table.

Comment: @realife - tweaking the 5 and 3 will change the size of the resulting table, hence the performance of the ultimate query.

Comment: We created a sampled table using `1000xlat - 700xlon`. It resulted to around 2 million rows and a typical search takes ~0.8sec. It's a good base and probably can be improved further. Thanks.